# Trigger javascript function onclick

Tags: javascript

I created an simple painting application, with the help of an script from mudcu, sketch.js.

I made some changes within the code, but now i have my problems to trigger an function that sets the color of the pencil.

```
var Sketch = function(config) { "use strict";
var that = this;
...........
var ctx2 = layer2d[2];
// Style object.
this.zoom = 1;

this.style = {
    tool: "brush",
    globalAlpha: 1,
    globalCompositeOperation: "source-over",
    strokeStyle: "#000",
    lineWidth: 5,
    lineCap: "round",
    lineJoin: "round"
```

My question is how can i set the "this.style" strokeStyle to for example "#D55151" when the user clicks an button?

Comment: Can you give us bigger part of the code and the html for the button

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery is a good solution for your problem:

```
<button id="myBtn">My Button</button>
```

JQuery

```
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
  // set you style
  that.style.strokeStyle = "#D55151"; // var that = this;
});
```

UPDATE:

The pure javascript answer :

```
document.getElementById('myBtn').onclick=function(){
   // set you style
  that.style.strokeStyle = "#D55151"; // var that = this;
};
```

Comment: From the `javascript` tag: *Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.*

Comment: And that won't work, since you appear to be dealing with the wrong `this`

Comment: Sorry but your solution didnt worked! I think the sketch has to be reinit?

Answer (score -1):

you can add:

```
function(config, style) {
    this.style = style || this.style = {
            tool: "brush",
            globalAlpha: 1,
            globalCompositeOperation: "source-over",
            strokeStyle: "#000",
            lineWidth: 5,
            lineCap: "round",
            lineJoin: "round"
        };
}
```

and call it like

```
$("#somebutton").on("click", function() {
    Sketch({config}, {overides style});
});
```

or better yet if you're using jQuery or underscore:

```
function(config, style) {
    this.style = $.extend({
            tool: "brush",
            globalAlpha: 1,
            globalCompositeOperation: "source-over",
            strokeStyle: "#000",
            lineWidth: 5,
            lineCap: "round",
            lineJoin: "round"
        }, style);
}
```

I prefer the second solution much safer...